# Firebase Hosting reverification shows nothing

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have a GCP project. Then I gave permission to a user A with email A@email. They connected it to Firebase and developed a project there with hosting enabled and verified. Then another user B came and I switched the ownership of the project to them and removed A from this. After ownership change, the hosting verification was re-triggered (as expected). However, since 1 week it only shows [image: this screen]

I tried searching for other people who had such an issue and nothing came about. I even wrote a bug report but for more than a week nobody has reached out to me and I am worried because the grace period is 1 month and I my project could go down. Have you heard of similar problems?

Edit from comment:

I can confirm that the error comes in Chrome and incognito (version: 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (32-bit)) and in Firefox and incognito (version: 72.0.2 (64-bit)). Opening the console gives error 503 for URLs `https://clients6.google.com/siteVerification/v1/webResource?verificationMethod=DNS_TXT&alt=json&key=` and `https://clients6.google.com/siteVerification/v1/token`.

Comment: *firebaser here* Did you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) yet? If not, please do so. If you did, can you give me the case number so that I can have a look?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your response! I did indeed wrote a bug report which but have missed the response. The response is that I need to 're-verify' the ownership of the site (which I obviously would like to but I cannot). The reference number is: ref:_00D1Ux0Jq._5003p2PGwzK:ref

Comment: Why can't you re-verify the ownership?

Comment: Because when I select 'Verify' the screen is empty and thus, I am not able to receive the token.

Comment: Ah right, got it. :) I pinged a few folks in our hosting team. In the meantime can you check if the problem persists: 1) in an incognito window, 2) if you disable all extensions, 3) in another browser? If so, 4) can you check if there are any error messages showing up in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Comment: I can confirm that the error comes in Chrome and incognito (version: 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (32-bit)) and in Firefox and incognito (version: 72.0.2 (64-bit)). Opening the console gives error 503 for sites [this](https://clients6.google.com/siteVerification/v1/webResource?verificationMethod=DNS_TXT&alt=json&key=) and [this](https://clients6.google.com/siteVerification/v1/token)

Comment: I can't find your case in our support system. Are you sure you filed a support ticket with the Firebase team (not the Cloud team)? Can you share the link of where you filed it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212402/discussion-between-agoranov-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to my company's license agreement with Google and the way Firebase Hosting is made. More details below.

Strangely enough, using GCP and Firebase require a GCP license. With this license you can do everything from adding/changing/modifing collections/projects. However, the functionality to 'Verify' your hosting site goes through the Google Console which is not included in the license.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this same thing. The problem turned out that I was using a *Google Workspace* account that did not have "Google Search Console" enabled for the domain I was logged in on.

To remedy, I had to login to my Workspace Admin, and go turn it on as shown below.

[image]